# failed `assert` does not throw `AssertionError` in dart with null-safety, any workaround?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, error-handling, dart-null-safety

as soon as I started transitioning to `null-safety`
I encountered this problem:
running the test below

```dart
//  ignore_for_file: avoid_catching_errors

import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test(
      'WHEN `AssertionError` is thrown '
      'THEN `Error` is `AssertionError`'
      '', () {
    Type? type;

    void fun() => throw AssertionError();

    try {
      fun();
    } on Error catch (e) {
      if (e is AssertionError) {
        type = e.runtimeType;
      }
    }

    expect(type, AssertionError);
  });
  test('WHEN `assertion` fails THEN throw `AssertionError`', () {
    Type? type;

    void fun() {
      assert(false);
    }

    try {
      fun();
    } on Error catch (e) {
      if (e is AssertionError) {
        type = e.runtimeType;
      }
    }

    expect(type, AssertionError);
  });

  test('WHEN `assertion fails THEN throwsA(AssertionError) should be true', () {
    bool fun() {
      assert(false);
      return true;
    }

    expect(fun, throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));
  });
}
```

outputs the following logs

```sh
00:00 +0: loading test/widget_test.dart                                                                                                                                                                
00:01 +0: loading test/widget_test.dart                                                                                                                                                                
00:01 +0: test/widget_test.dart: WHEN `AssertionError` is thrown THEN `Error` is `AssertionError`                                                                                                      
00:01 +1: test/widget_test.dart: WHEN `AssertionError` is thrown THEN `Error` is `AssertionError`                                                                                                      
00:01 +1: test/widget_test.dart: WHEN `assertion` fails THEN throw `AssertionError`                                                                                                                    
00:01 +1 -1: test/widget_test.dart: WHEN `assertion` fails THEN throw `AssertionError` [E]                                                                                                             
  Expected: Type:<AssertionError>
    Actual: Type:<_AssertionError>

  package:test_api            expect
  test/widget_test.dart 39:5  main.<fn>


00:01 +1 -1: test/widget_test.dart: WHEN `assertion fails THEN throwsA(AssertionError) should be true                                                                                                  
00:01 +2 -1: test/widget_test.dart: WHEN `assertion fails THEN throwsA(AssertionError) should be true                                                                                                  
00:01 +2 -1: Some tests failed.                                                                                                                                                                        
pub failed (1; 00:01 +2 -1: Some tests failed.
)
```

note that attempting to use `_AssertionError` outputs the error

> The name '_AssertionError' isn't defined, so it can't be used in an
> 'is' expression. Try changing the name to the name of an existing
> type, or creating a type with the name '_AssertionError'.

---

please avoid answering `you are not supposed to catch errors`
the code below is purely demonstrative
and I'm encountering the problem writing tests
while expect(fun(), throwsA(AssertionError)); has been included in the code sample it won't fit my use case

---

this is not a bug, but an intended behavior, see [issue 45191](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45191)

> You shouldn't expect `assert(false)` to throw an object whose run-time type is `AssertionError`, it is only guaranteed to throw an object which is typable as such (that is, an object whose run-time type is a subtype of `AssertionError`), and that's probably the reason why the test `expect(type, AssertionError);` fails.

---

my doctor and my pubspec below

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.97, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.1.0-11.0.pre.97 at /home/francesco/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision c14c8d8177 (2 hours ago), 2021-03-03 21:40:34 -0800
    • Engine revision 72bbc5d92c
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-93.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/francesco/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/francesco/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /snap/bin/chromium

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
    • cmake version 3.10.2
    • ninja version 1.8.2
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Linux
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Chromium 89.0.4389.72 snap

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~/project
```

```yaml
name: issue
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.16.5
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [`throwsA`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/test_api/throwsA.html) `Matcher` instead? (`expect(fun, throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));`) Alternatively if you're prefer using your own manual `try`-`catch`, then set a boolean flag instead.

Comment: good point, thanks... but it fails as well... updating the question

Comment: It failed because you didn't use the `throwsA` `Matcher` correctly.  Please read its documentation (and the code I suggested in my comment).

Comment: To be clear: `throwsA` matches against a `Function`; that means `fun`, not `fun()`.  You must not invoke your function, because then it will throw an exception and unwind the call stack *before* the `Matcher` ever gets to do anything.

Comment: FYI, according to your latest edit, the test using `throwsA` succeeded.

Comment: it does, but doesn't fit my use case " 'while expect(fun(), throwsA(AssertionError)); has been included in the code sample it won't fit my use case' "

Comment: Can you explain *why* it doesn't fit your use case?  Or, again, why not just set a boolean flag instead depending on `.runtimeType` (which is a bad idea)?

Comment: In the real code I'm trying to "capture" a specific error and `rethrow` everything else, in particular assertions, `Foo as Bar`, I know the "you shouldn't catch errors" rule,
but I was doing it very precisely and this behavior seems to be new to null-safety... the only thing holding me back from migrating is this NEW behavior

Comment: I think your original question (whether there's a way to catch `AssertionError` in tests) has been answered.  You should have a separate question for your actual problem (how can you capture a specific error and rethrow everything else).

Comment: the test is just a code sample, I cannot use `throwA`, the point made by @Erik-Ernst gave me an idea about how to fix it... I need to try it out before opening a bottle of champagne

Comment: You asked a specific question about `AssertionError`, which turned out to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Anyway, if a boolean flag also isn't good enough, instead of storing the `Type`, you could just save `e` and check `expect(e, isA<AssertionError>())`.

Comment: I asked, quote `failed assert does not throw AssertionError in dart with null-safety, any workaround?` end quote, never mentioned of tests and I've specified `the code below is purely demonstrative`, your proposed `expect(e, isA<AssertionError>())` doesn't work for my use case... I'm still looking for a workaround; most likely I'll end up implementing custom errors and custom `assert` and somthing more creative for `Foo as Bar` (that presents the same problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't expect `assert(false)` to throw an object whose run-time type is `AssertionError`, it is only guaranteed to throw an object which is typable as such (that is, an object whose run-time type is a subtype of `AssertionError`), and that's probably the reason why the test `expect(type, AssertionError);` fails.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom error that extends `AssertionError` and a function that emulates `assert` for my specific use case, thank you for the insight :)